# Android Studio how to allow to edit files that are not in Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 0.8.0 does not allow editing files that are not in the project, this is by default. I have searched in File->Settings->Editor but found nothing to make the files editable. The editor just behaves like the file is read-only.

Comment: having the same troubles with some python file :/